# mapStateToProps is not reflecting in component after action dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer which looks like this:

```
export default function reducer(state={
  fetching: false,
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_REQUEST': {
      return {...state, fetching: true}
    }
...
return state
```

I dispatch action to it from compoenent and in component I have:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
}
```

My problem is:
1. In `mapStateToProps` state contains `login.fetching: true`
2. In component right after dispatching action to reducer `this.props.login.fetching` contains `false`.
3. In component `render()` method `this.props.login.fetching` is `true`.

Why in  case **2.** it is still `false`, is it possible and what I am missing here?

Action dispatch:

```
onLoginPress = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(loginUser(this.state.email.trim(), this.state.password.trim()))
console.log(this.props);
```

Comment: can you show the code for your component specifically where you are dispatching the action

Comment: i wouldn't expect to see the props directly after your dispatch reflect the change in state. that would would only appear on the re-render, which by the sounds of it is what you are seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is really simple, you get `false` right after you `dispatch` an action because of the `async nature` of Javascript, so even before your `props` get modified your `console.log(this.props)` get called and hence it displays the previous value. However the `render()` function gets called when you state from reducer changes and hence it displays the updated value.

What you need there is the `Promise` on dispatch

Use this

```
onLoginPress = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(loginUser(this.state.email.trim(), this.state.password.trim())).then(() => {
   console.log(this.props);
})
```

I hope, I was able to explain it properly.

Comment: You explained it perfect. Didn't know that I can use promise on dispatch.

Comment: Thanks, Glad to have helped :)